# Customize Jackson XML response in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

At the moment I have a Spring REST service which is able to generate JSON and XML but the XML response in not exactly what I'm looking for.

This is what I've build so far is:

The XSD object

```
<xs:element name="project">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="projectBase"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="projectBase">
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute type="xs:anyURI" name="self" use="optional" />
</xs:complexType>
```

The POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Controller

```
@ApiOperation(value = "GET",
        notes = "Returns a list of exisiting projects.")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/smartask.projectsV1+xml", "application/smartask.projectsV1+json"})
public List<be.smartask.api.model.smartask.Project> getProjects(@ApiParam(value = "page of found projects", required = false) @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                                                @ApiParam(value = "size(min:5, max:50) of projects on a page", required = false) @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") int size) throws ServiceException, ConversionException {
    String uri = getURLWithContextPath(this.request);
    List<be.smartask.api.model.smartask.Project> projects = projectConverter.convertToObjectList(projectService.findAll(page, size), uri);
    return projects;
}
```

The result I get when I execute this getProjects method is

```
<List xmlns="">
  <item>
    <name>project1</name>
    <id>7a666889-9b03-4790-8100-d41a9de66a63</id>
    <self>http://localhost/ask/projects/7a666889-9b03-4790-8100-d41a9de66a63</self>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>project2</name>
    <id>f784ede1-d019-46e9-b7a4-83c51d6f7d8e</id>
    <self>http://localhost/ask/projects/f784ede1-d019-46e9-b7a4-83c51d6f7d8e</self>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>project3</name>
    <id>936e3ed9-b8c6-46ab-9570-60dcfcaaa670</id>
    <self>http://localhost/ask/projects/936e3ed9-b8c6-46ab-9570-60dcfcaaa670</self>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>project4</name>
    <id>4eaa6045-bbc4-423d-8bae-1da11692114b</id>
    <self>http://localhost/ask/projects/4eaa6045-bbc4-423d-8bae-1da11692114b</self>
  </item>
</List>
```

Which is already pretty close, but I would like to replace the List and Item tags with Projects and Project.

So far I've tried to add various annotations like

- @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
- @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
- @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true, localName = "projects")
- @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "project")
- @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "project")

The first 4 I used on my controller method and the last one I used on the generated object (both Project and ProjectBase), but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong or what have I forgotten to accomplish this?

I would like to keep my JSON output as it is though

```
[
  {
    "name": "project1",
    "id": "7a666889-9b03-4790-8100-d41a9de66a63",
    "self": "http://localhost/ask/projects/7a666889-9b03-4790-8100-d41a9de66a63"
  }
]
```

and not

```
{
    "Projects": {
        "Project": [{
            "name": "project1",
            "id": "7a666889-9b03-4790-8100-d41a9de66a63",
            "self": "http://localhost/ask/projects/7a666889-9b03-4790-8100-d41a9de66a63"
        }]
    }
}
```

Edit #1

Someone suggested me to take a look at this guide:

https://pascaldimassimo.com/2010/04/13/how-to-return-a-single-json-list-out-of-mappingjacksonjsonview/

but haven't succeeded in making this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution wasn't trying to adapt the XML output but to adapt the JSON output. I did have to create a wrapping object "Projects".

```
<xs:element name="projects">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="project" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:appinfo>
                    <annox:annotate target="getter">@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue</annox:annotate>
                    </xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

which results in

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "project"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "projects")
public class Projects {

    protected List<Project> project;

    @JsonValue
    public List<Project> getProject() {
    if (project == null) {
        project = new ArrayList<Project>();
    }
    return this.project;
    }

}
```

By annotating the getter with @JsonValue it will remove the wrapping "Projects" object in the JSON output

You do need some additional setup for generating annotation though, see: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin